# Is it possible to obtain the number of tweets that contain certain keyword over a certain period of time?

Tags: twitter

E.g. I would like to obtain the number of tweets on [this page](https://twitter.com/search?q=since_time%3A1613772000%20until_time%3A1613775600%20%23nasa&src=typed_query) (after it is fully expanded). Is it possible?

As far as I can see, Twitter API, including the [academic product](https://developer.twitter.com/en/solutions/academic-research/application-info) does not provide a straightforward option to obtain the number of tweets over a specific period of time (one would need to request for each single tweets, and the number of tweets that can be requested is limited per month).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Today, counts are only available in the premium and enterprise APIs, not in the new v2 API. You can get timeseries and counts but you’ll be looking at a paid API.